# Require.js not finding dependancies

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, gruntjs

I am using require.js, and in my config file I am calling the following to start the app (using this page as a reference: http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/):

```
require(['backbone', 'jquery', 'app'], function(Backbone, $, App) {
    console.log('no dependancies loaded');
});
```

However when it complies (via grunt.js) it doesn't load backbone and jquery - it doesn't even list any dependancies. However if I remove the app require backbone and jquery are loaded, e.g.:

```
require(['backbone', 'jquery'], function(Backbone, $) {
    console.log('dependancies loaded');
});
```

main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery',
        underscore: 'vendor/underscore',
        backbone: 'vendor/backbone'
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: [],
        backbone: {
            deps: ['vendor/underscore', 'vendor/jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        }
    }
});

require(['backbone', 'jquery', 'App'], function(Backbone, $, App) {

    App.initialize();

});
```

app.js

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'router'], function($, _, Backbone, Router){
  var initialize = function() {
    // Pass in our Router module and call it's initialize function
    Router.initialize();
  };

  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

No error messages are shown. Why does it not pick them up?

Comment: Where is 'app' module defined? It's hard to tell anything with just this code.

Comment: I haven't defined it anywhere. I was following the same process as the backbone tutorial link, which says "Modules are loaded relatively to the boot strap and always append with ".js". So the module "app" will load "app.js" which is in the same directory as the bootstrap.". Should I be including App in my main config file?

Comment: Can you paste the code of app.js, at least the define part?

Comment: Added main.js and app.js

Comment: 1 downvote and 2 votes to close?! I've not used requirejs before so it's difficult to know what I should be adding to the question or not :/

Comment: try change shim backbone - `deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],

Comment: Yeah, SO can be a bit too harsh sometimes. In your upper example you have 'app', but in the main.js you have 'App' (upper case). Is this intentional? Assuming that's just a typo, can you see the request for app.js in the network tab & does it return the correct file?

Comment: @Sergey thanks that was my problem! If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xylar, change shim backbone - `deps: ['underscore', 'jquery']